# Implicit types for numbers in C

Tags: c, types, casting, implicit-conversion, coercion

What are the implicit types for numbers in C? If, for example, I have a decimal number in a calculation, is the decimal always treated as a double? If I have a non-decimal number, is it always treated as an int? What if my non-decimal number is larger than an int value?

I'm curious because this affects type conversion and promotion. For instance, if I have the following calculation:

```
float a = 1.0 / 25;
```

Is `1.0` treated as a double and `25` treated as an int? Is `25` then promoted to a double, the calculation performed at double precision and then the result converted to a float?

What about:

```
double b = 1 + 2147483649;   // note that the number is larger than an int value
```

Comment: What could we tell you that's not already covered in the standard?

Comment: My solution always was, 'let the compiler tell you' ;)

Comment: 1.0 is a float and 25 is an integer in the expression. The division was coerced to a float but if you dropped the decimal point on the 1.0 it's an integer and the division is on two integers (0) See my answer below for more info.

Comment: @lukecampbell In C, `1.0` has type `double`, not `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number has neither a decimal point nor an exponent, it is an integer of some sort; by default, an `int`.

If the number has a decimal point or an exponent, it is a floating point number of some sort; by default, a `double`.

That's about it.  You can append suffixes to numbers (such as `ULL` for `unsigned long long`) to specify the type more precisely.  Otherwise (simplifying a little), integers are the smallest `int` type (of type `int` or longer) that will hold the value.

In your examples, the code is:

```
float a = 1.0 / 25;
double b = 1 + 2147483649;
```

The value of `a` is calculated by noting that `1.0` is a double and `25` is an integer.  When processing the division, the `int` is converted to a `double`, the calculation is performed (producing a `double`), and the result is then coerced into a `float` for assignment to `a`.  All of this can be done by the compiler, so the result will be pre-computed.

Similarly, on a system with 32-bit `int`, the value `214783649` is too big to be an `int`, so it will be treated as a signed type bigger than `int` (either `long` or `long long`); the `1` is added (yielding the same type), and then that value is converted to a `double`.  Again, it is all done at compile time.

These computations are governed by the same rules as other computations in C.

---

The type rules for integer constants are detailed in §6.4.4.1 Integer constants of ISO/IEC 9899:1999.  There's a table which details the types depending on the suffix (if any) and the type of constant (decimal vs octal or hexadecimal).  For decimal constants, the value is always a signed integer; for octal or hexadecimal constants, the type can be signed or unsigned as required, and as soon as the value fits.  Thanks to [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: 2147483649 is a decimal constant without suffix, by 6.4.4.1 it will be of the first type of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` that can hold the value, not `unsigned int`. Nevertheless, good answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

The standard has a general guideline for what you can expect but compilers have a superset of rules that encompass the standard as well as rules for optimizing. The above link discusses some of the the generalities you can expect. If you are concerned about the implicit coercion it is typically good practice to use explicit casting.

Keep in mind that the size of the primitive types is not guaranteed.

```
1.0 / 25
```

Evaluates to a double because one of the operands is a double. If you changed it to `1/25` the evaluation is performed as two integers and evaluates to `0`.

```
double b = 1 + 2147483649;
```

The right side is evaluated as an integer and then coerced to a double during assignment.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. It only explains what Type Conversion is. [This part of the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) is better, but most likely is not comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

actually. in your example you may get a compiler warning. You'd either write 1.0f to make it a float to start with, or explicitly cast your result before assigning it.